# unable to create a dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to create this dic :

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
[{"numberfirst": x, "numbersecond":y} for (x,y) in (a,b)]
```

My goal is to get that :

```
[
 {"numberfirst": 1, "numbersecond":4},
 {"numberfirst": 2, "numbersecond":5},
 {"numberfirst": 3, "numbersecond":6},
]
```

But I got that :

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Anyone who can help me ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: And to be precise you are doing list comprehension, not dict comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip(a,b)` instead `(a,b)`

```
l = [{"numberfirst": x, "numbersecond":y} for (x,y) in zip(a,b)]
```